# Need help on extracting and spliting url in to seperate variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have one raw input from end user in to a variable as below
`javascript:DS('https://HS/v1/dev/A/Machinename/SNAPNAME','XXXXX')`

1. I want to extract url from the above input.
2. I want to split the url using '/' in to seperate variables.

Input :

`$DSURL = "javascript:DS('https://HS/v1/dev/A/Machinename/SNAPNAME','XXXXX')"`

```
[regex]$regex = '(?<=https:\/\/\HS\\/v1\/dev\/A\?t=)(.*)(?=' )'

$regex.Matches($DSURL).Value
```

$1 = `https://HS/v1/dev/A/Machinename/SNAPNAME`
$2 = `Machinename`
$3 = `SNAPNAME`

But it is not working,
I think the regex used is wrong,
Please help

Comment: So basically Its just an API call and not actually a URl where you will get www and .com or .in or something that sort of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this uses the `[uri]` type accelerator to convert the uri *string* into a uri *object*. then it uses the `.Segments` property to grab the last two segments and put them into $Vars.

you may want to look at the various properties stored in the `$UriObject` variable for some other interesting info. [*grin*]

```
$DSUrl = "javascript:DS('https://HS/v1/dev/A/SpiffyDoodleServer/SomeSortOfThing','XXXXX')"

$CleanedDSU = $DSUrl.Split('(')[1].Split(',')[0].Trim("'")
$UriObject = [uri]$CleanedDSU

$MachineName = $UriObject.Segments[-2].Trim('/')
$SnapName = $UriObject.Segments[-1]

$DSUrl
$CleanedDSU
$MachineName
$SnapName
```

output ...

```
javascript:DS('https://HS/v1/dev/A/SpiffyDoodleServer/SomeSortOfThing','XXXXX')
https://HS/v1/dev/A/SpiffyDoodleServer/SomeSortOfThing
SpiffyDoodleServer
SomeSortOfThing
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to pull this and it is picking the output URL properly.

```
$text = "javascript:DS('https://HS/v1/dev/A/Machinename/SNAPNAME','XXXXX')"
($text | Select-String -Pattern @"
(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
"@).Matches.Value
```

OUTPUT:

```
https://HS/v1/dev/A/Machinename/SNAPNAME','XXXXX
```

Hope it helps.